# difference between 2 types of downcasting

Tags: java, netbeans, casting

```
public class {
    main() {
        // What is the different implications of these 2 down casts

        Superclass tRefVar = new SubClass();

        // Down cast example 1
        SubClass aVar = (SubClass) tRefVar;  

        // Down cast example 2
        ((SubClass) tRefVar).someMethodInSubClass();  
    }
}
```

implications, wise, what are the differences between example 1 cast, and example 2 cast?

Comment: It's the same. The second example is just calling a method directly after casting the object stored in the variable

Comment: If you call the method on aVar, you'll get the same result... If you don't need aVar for other operations, you can use the second example.

Answer (score 1):

There is virtually no difference. The first example creates a new local variable, and the second example doesn't. That's it.

To peek under the hood a bit and verify that, let's consider this simple class, with two methods that do essentially what you're doing in your example:

```
public class Downcasts {
  public int stringLength1(Object o) {
    String s = (String) o;
    return s.length();
  }

  public int stringLength2(Object o) {
    return ((String) o).length();
  }
}
```

The bytecode for these methods (which you can see with `javap -c Downcasts`) are:

```
public int stringLength1(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
     0: aload_1
     1: checkcast     #2                  // class java/lang/String
     4: astore_2
     5: aload_2
     6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
     9: ireturn

public int stringLength2(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
     0: aload_1
     1: checkcast     #2                  // class java/lang/String
     4: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
     7: ireturn
```

The first method does these things:

- `String s = (String) o`:

  - loads `o` to the stack
  - checks that it's a String
  - stores that into register 2
- `return s.length()`:

  - loads register 2 to the stack (that's the one we just saved)
  - invokes `String::length` (a virtual function)  on it
  - returns the result

The second method does:

- `return ((String) o).length()`:

  - loads `o` to the stack
  - checks that it's a String
  - invokes `String::length` (a virtual function) on it
  - returns the result

Comment: thanks that helped me understand it more. really i think, my main confusion for a down cast is what exactly it does. is it used just for overriden methods?

Comment: No, it's only for methods that don't exist on the super class. In my example, there's no method `Object::length`, so `o.length()` won't compile at all. You have to tell the compiler, "this thing that you only know is an Object, well, it's actually a String" -- and that's exactly that casting does. In fact, that's _all_ that casting does -- it doesn't change the object at all or "turn it into" a String, which is sometimes a point of confusion. It's like if I told you I had a car, and then said "oh by the way, it's a 2-door coup." That second statement didn't change the car at all.

Answer (score 0):

The casting is no different. Example #1 uses a temporary local variable and Example #2 does not.

The difference here is exactly the same as e.g.

```
int i = 0;

int j = i * 2;  // uses a temporary local
result = j + 1; //

result = (i * 2) + 1; // does not use a temporary local
```

Answer (score 0):

These are identical, you use

```
SubClass aVar = (SubClass) tRefVar
```

If you want to reuse `aVar` more than once

Comment: Or you use it if you just don't want some huge complex and esoteric-looking expression.